# Load a ui.Image asset based on pixel density

Tags: flutter

I have this code which loads a [ui.Image](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) using an async function:

```
Future<ui.Image> _loadImage() async {
  final imageData = await rootBundle.load('assets/some_image.jpg');

  var imageBytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();

  return await decodeImageFromList(imageBytes);
}
```

But I would like to base it on [AssetImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html) instead as it loads the correct asset version for the device pixel density. Or make it resolution aware by some other means.